# Round to Next .05 in C

Tags: c

Consider a float value like **1.82** set by the user. How do I find the next highest .05 value? For the given example the next highest value is 1.85.

Is there a simple way or does it take a complex algorithm?  I tried to use `floor` and `ceiling` functions to come up with the distance from the float to the next highest and lowest Integers. But I'm not sure how to proceed once I have that info.

Thanks.

Comment: Rounding `n` to next multiple of `0.05` => rounding `n*2` to next multiple of `0.1` => rounding `n*2*10` to the next higher integer.  Do you want to round `0.05` to `0.10` or keep it as it is?

Comment: You are not storing money in a `double`, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiply by 20, use ceiling, divide by 20.

Answer (score 0):

A great useful and informative resource for [Rounding methods](http://www.diycalculator.com/sp-round.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Code for @Justin's answer. Note that this is very easy to generalize.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    double numbers[] = {
        1.82, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 10000000000.849,
    };

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]); ++i) {
        double scaled = ceil(20 * numbers[i]);
        printf("%.2f\n", scaled/20.0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float fixedCeil(float num, float factor)
{
  float steps = 1.0f / factor;
  return ceil(steps*num)/steps;
}

assert(fixedCeil(2.43f, 0.05f) == 2.45f);
```

(assert is just fictional)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
    // Rounds X to the nearest Y
    double round(double x, double y)
    {
        return floor(x / y + 0.5) * y;
    }
```