# Java - How to round up float (or BigDecimal ) value by 0.5?

Tags: java, rounding

Seems simple question but **I really suck at math** and few examples online I've searched seems not working for me. (the result just return the same value as input etc)

For instance.. but its in C not Java
[Round to Next .05 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302927/round-to-next-05-in-c)

So my goal is I have `%.1f` format `float` or `double` or `big decimal` and wanting to **round it up to nearest .5**

```
example:

1.3 --> 1.5
5.5 --> 5.5
2.4 --> 2.5
3.6 --> 4.0
7.9 --> 8.0
```

I tried following example but didn't work :( below just output 1.3 which is original value. I wanted it to be 1.5

```
public class tmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      double foo = 1.3;

      double mid = 20 * foo;

      System.out.println("mid " + mid);

      double out = Math.ceil(mid);

      System.out.println("out after ceil " + out);

      System.out.printf("%.1f\n", out/20.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiplying (and later dividing) by 2, not 20, should do the trick.

Comment: omg it works!! :D thanks! I should have studied Math being developer! I could even do the same Round down with floor() too, awesome

Answer (score 20):

Here's a simple method:

```
public static float roundToHalf(float x) {
    return (float) (Math.ceil(x * 2) / 2);
}
```

This doubles the value, takes its ceiling, and cuts it back in half.

Answer (score 5):

```
 double nearestPoint5 = Math.ceil(d * 2) / 2;
```

Answer (score 5):

The below formula does not work well for number like 2.16

```
public static float roundToHalf(float x) {
  return (float) (Math.ceil(x * 2) / 2);
}
```

The correct answer should be 2.0, but the above method gives 2.5

The correct code should be:

```
public static double round(float d)
{
    return 0.5 * Math.round(d * 2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the [Big Decimal Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) about why a String is used in the constructor

```
 public static double round(double d, int decimalPlace){
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using a function, you can do

```
double rounded = (double)(long)(x * 2 + 0.5) / 2;
```

Note: this will round towards infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the other answers round incorrectly (`Math.round` should be used, not `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`), and others only work for rounding to 0.5 (which is what the question asked, yes). Here's a simple method that correctly rounds to the nearest arbitrary double, with a check to assure that it's a positive number.

```
public static double roundToNearest(double d, double toNearest) {
    if (toNearest <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "toNearest must be positive, encountered " + toNearest);
    }
    return Math.round(d/toNearest) * toNearest;
}
```