# Android round up .05 to 0.1

Tags: java, android

this is i want the result in java

1.05 rounded to 1.1
1.15 rounded to 1.2

but i have tried

```
global.UnitPrice = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", 1.05)));
```

result = 1.00, should be 1.10 ?

i have tried this method
[Round to Next .05 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302927/round-to-next-05-in-c)

```
Multiply by 20, use ceiling, divide by 20.
```

but can't work? any easier method? or formal way?

Comment: `result = 1.00, should be 1.10 ?`. NO, it's correct. Roundings occur after 0.5: 1.49 => 1.00, while 1.51 => 2.00.

Comment: @Artoo Detoo i want the result 1.05 become 1.1 , any way?

Comment: Gabe Sechan gave you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you expected this to work.  String.format would return either "1.05" or "1.04" depending on how 1.05 translates into binary (it won't ever be an exact number).  Parsing it as a double will return a double either just less than 1.04, just less than 1.05, just greater than 1.04, or just greater than 1.05.  In all cases that would round down to 1.0, as Math.round will round to the nearest whole number.

The other method should work fine.

```
global.UnitPrice = Math.ciel(1.05*10)/10;
```

Because by your description you don't actually want to round to .05, you want to round to the nearest .1.  As with all floating point numbers remember that an exact 1.05 is an impossible value to store, so you may have floating point conversion problems.